# "Use something to your advantage" in one word?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

How would you say "use something to your advantage" in one word?
Something like "benefit from" with a positive connotation.

Comment: 'Benefit from' is fine. I would stick with that.

Comment: Your example seems poorly chosen.

Answer (score 2):

**capitalize** on (something)  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/capitalize)

> To take advantage of a particular opportunity or situation for one's
>   benefit.

Answer (score 2):

**[profit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/profit)** [from something]

> It would profit him to take some computer classes.
>
> The island profits from tourism.

**[exploit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exploit)** [something]

> He has never fully exploited his talents.
>
> Top athletes are able to exploit their opponents' weaknesses.

Comment: Exploit was my first thought too.

Comment: @moonstar Mine too, even though it has gained some negative connotations in some contexts.